# If $S$ is an isometry, why is $\sqrt{S^{*}S}$ a positive and hence self adjoint operator?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to show that $S$ being an isometry leads to the fact that all singular values of $S$ equal 1. I know a key part of the proof is showing that $\sqrt{S^{*}S}$ is self adjoint so that I can apply the spectral theorem. Can anyone guide me as to why the square root is self adjoint? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $S$ is an isometry, then $\|Sx\| = \|x\|$ for all $x$. From the polarization identity we see that $\langle Sx, Sy \rangle = \langle x, y \rangle$ for all $x,y$. It follows from this that $S^* S = I$, hence all singular values are $1$.